# How to split array into another based on attribute value?

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array that contains several type of dict, as example:

```
arr = [
    {'type': 'employee.update', ...}, 
    {'type': 'job.started', ...}, 
    {'type': 'meeting.xpto', ...}
    ...
]
```

How can I split the "main" array by prefix of type? Is necessary to iterate over entire array for every prefix?

```
employess_actions = list(filter(lambda x: x['type'].startswith('employee.'), arr))
job_actions = list(filter(lambda x: x['type'].startswith('job.'), arr))
meeting_actions = list(filter(lambda x: x['type'].startswith('meeting.'), arr))
```

Is there any performatic way of achieve it? Or a pythonic way.

Comment: Wouldn't it simpler to just loop over `arr` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a (default)dict for collecting the elements by prefix:

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for o in arr:
    result[o["type"][:o["type"].index(".")]].append(o)
```

This assumes of course that all those types have a "." in them.

For example, if:

```
arr = [
    {"type": "employee.update"}, 
    {"type": "job.started"}, 
    {"type": "meeting.xpto"},
    {"type": "job.ended"}
]
```

then the resulting `result` is

```
{
  "employee": [{"type": "employee.update"}],
  "job":      [{"type": "job.started"}, {"type": "job.ended"}],
  "meeting":  [{"type": "meeting.xpto"}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over `arr`, group each *type* with a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) using the the prefix as the key. We can use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the type on `.`, then unpack the prefix using *tuple unpacking*.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

arr = [
    {'type': 'employee.update'}, 
    {'type': 'job.started'}, 
    {'type': 'meeting.xpto'}
]

types = defaultdict(list)
for dic in arr:
    prefix, _ = dic["type"].split(".")
    types[prefix].append(dic)

print(types)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'employee': [{'type': 'employee.update'}], 'job': [{'type': 'job.started'}], 'meeting': [{'type': 'meeting.xpto'}]})
```

If we want to only append the type and not the full dictionary:

```
types[prefix].append(dic["type"])
```

Which will give instead:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'employee': ['employee.update'], 'job': ['job.started'], 'meeting': ['meeting.xpto']})
```